# how to read content of an XML file from NSOpenPanel

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsopenpanel

I am trying to copy the content of an XML file after selection from NSOpenPanel in cocoa.
So lets say this XML file could be any where on desktop or other directories. Once I get the file Path, I am trying to read/copy the content to an NSMutableData like following.

I have filePath:

```
NSString* filePath = [files objectAtIndex:0];
```

*e.g.: file://localhost/Users/Me/Documents/XMLFiles/FileA.xml*

Trying to get the content and copy to an NSMutableData

```
xmlData  = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

or

```
xmlData  = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath]];
```

Comment: Why do you need the XML as raw data?! (Through NSData).  Why not as a NSMutableString?!  Why mutable at all?!  Are you trying to parse it?!  What are you trying to do with the XML data?!

Comment: What problem are you having that you need help with?

Comment: I cant get the content of the file from the file path, should the file only be in the NSBundle?

Comment: It doesnt have anything to do with what I want to do with xml, it is one step behind that i have problem. To actually get the content of the xml. and yes I want it as nsdata and mutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you truly want the data under NSMutableData form then the following should help you:

```
NSMutableData *theData = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfURL:[[theOpenPanel URLs] objectAtIndex:0]];
```

But I don't think that would be very useful.  *Why have xml as raw data?  Mutable at that!!*

Are you looking for the string so you can manually look at the text document?!  Then perhaps this is what you're looking for :  NSString's  [stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithContentsOfFile%3aencoding%3aerror%3a)

Perhaps you want to parse it afterwards?!  Then I'd suggest reading on [NSXMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html).